# Json DateTime Conversion returning new date time in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a web api controller method that is accepting a composite object where one of the properties is a DateTime.  When I post the object as XML everything works fine.  If I post it as JSON however, it fails.

In order to get some more information on why it might be failing, I've added a custom datetime converter, just reusing the basic IsoDateTimeConverter that comes with Json.Net, adn by placing a breakpoint on the converted value, I can see that the value converts fine, however when it gets to the model, the property is populated with a new datetime and not the value I am sending.  Sending the exact same model as XML works fine.

I'm a little confused as to the sequence of events and how it can go from being converted into a datetime object and then instantly lost by the time the model is bound.  I'm using the Json.Net IsoDateTimeConverter at both ends of the interaction for serialising and deserialising.

JSON Settings:

```
NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
Converters = new JsonConverter[]
{
    new StringEnumConverter(),
    new IsoDateTimeConverter()
}
```

Custom converter (using IsoDateTimeConverter) used for deserialisation at the web api end:

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    IsoDateTimeConverter isoConverter;

    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        isoConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        isoConverter.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var returned = isoConverter.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        return returned;
    }
}
```

Date property on the model (at both ends)

```
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Json format being posted:

```
"DateOfBirth":"1980-02-01T00:00:00"
```

Value at converter:

```
{01/02/1980 00:00:00}
```

Value at model in controller:

```
{01/01/0001 00:00:00}
```

The returned variable when breakpointed is showing the correct deserialised datetime, however the model straight afterwards is a new datetime.

Rather confused as to how this can deserialise and the decide that it hasn't straight after!  Any help greatly appreciated.

On further investigation, it seems that the json binder is also failing to bind properties in general - a load of basic string properties are not binding correctly, so this might be a part of a different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this wasn't to do with the JSON - the JSON was deserialising correctly, as I'd found by overriding the date converter.  The problem was that the object had required fields on it which under Web API need [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] also in order for the required fields to be enforced.  The problem lay in the fact that the rest of the object was not decorated with [DataMember] attributes so they were being ignored - I assume when the model was bound.

Irritating bug to track down, especially when the resolution was so simple...

Answer (score 4):

Json does not do dates. Pass them back as strings and parse them in your client script.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: The conclusion of the blog post is to use the json serialiser settings that I have posted in the code sample of the blog.  I shall update the question for a little more clarity as the json date is being converted, it's just going awry between conversion and model binding.

Comment: might help to post the relevant lines of your model (do you have  `DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }`?)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function ConvertDateTime(dt) {
        var cdt = new Date();
        var dateString = dt.substr(6);
        var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
        var month = currentTime.getMonth();
        var m = months[month];
        var day = currentTime.getDate();
        var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
        var hr = currentTime.getHours();
        var mi = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var date = day + "/" + m + "/" + year + " " + hr + ":" + mi;
        return date;
    }
```